# MVVM - Grid not updating when directly updating collection in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to implement a Tic Tac Toe game in WPF using the MVVM design pattern. The game works fine right now, but the problem appears when I try to reset the game to start over. In that case what I do is update the collection directly and then the grid in the window doesn't update to the new values.

In addition to that, I would appreciate some feedback on my implementation from a MVVM perspective.
Here is my implementation:

BoardView.xaml:

```
<Grid Name="boardGrid" Background="White">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="Label_Click"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[0], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[1], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[2], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[3], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[4], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[5], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[6], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[7], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Board[8], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
```

BoardView.xaml.cs:

```
private BoardViewModel _viewModel;
        public BoardView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new BoardViewModel();
            this.DataContext = _viewModel;
        }

        private void Label_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _viewModel.LabelClick(sender);
        }
```

Board.cs:

```
private string[] tiles;

        public Board()
        {
            tiles = new string[9];

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                tiles[i] = TurnSymbol._.ToString();
        }

        public string[] Tiles
        {
            get { return tiles; }
            set { tiles = value; }
        }
```

And the relevant part from the BoardViewModel.cs:

```
enum TurnSymbol
    {
        x,
        o,
        _
    }
internal class BoardViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private TurnSymbol currentSymbol;
        private Board board;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public string[] Board
        {
            get { return board.Tiles; }
            set
            {
                board.Tiles = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Board));
            }
        }

        public BoardViewModel()
        {
            board = new Board();
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) 
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        internal void LabelClick(object sender)
        {
            if((string)((Label)sender).Content == TurnSymbol._.ToString())
            {
                ((Label)sender).Content = currentSymbol.ToString();
                nextSymbol();

                //Need completion
                IsGameOver();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This cell is already filled! Choose another one.");
            }
        }

        private bool HandleGameOverMessage(string winningSymbol)
        {
            if(MessageBox.Show($"Game over! {winningSymbol} wins!", "Play again?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void HandleGameOver(string winningSymbol)
        {
            //Need completion
            bool playAgain = HandleGameOverMessage(winningSymbol);

            //Not needed but for extra clarity
            if(playAgain) 
                Reset();
        }

        private void Reset()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                Board[i] = TurnSymbol._.ToString();

            currentSymbol = TurnSymbol.x;

            MessageBox.Show("x starts!", "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

        internal bool IsGameOver()
        {
            //Check rows
            if (board.Tiles[0] != TurnSymbol._.ToString() && board.Tiles[0] == board.Tiles[1] && board.Tiles[1] == board.Tiles[2])
            {
                HandleGameOver(board.Tiles[1]);
            }
            else if (board.Tiles[3] != TurnSymbol._.ToString() && board.Tiles[3] == board.Tiles[4] && board.Tiles[4] == board.Tiles[5])
            ...

            return false;
        }
    }
```

I tried adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in xaml.
I also debugged the application and I can see that the Board property and board.Tiles are updated and show the correct values, so my guess is that I'm missing something or I did something wrong with the binding.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the Labels, use an ObservableCollection instead of a string array:

```
public class BoardViewModel
{
    // an ObservableCollection with 9 empty strings
    public ObservableCollection<string> Board { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<string>(
            Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(i => ""));
}
```

Instead of explicitly creating 9 Label elements in XAML, use an ItemsControl that has its `ItemsSource` property bound to the `Board` property of your view model. The ItemsControl uses a UniformGrid as its `ItemsPanel` and declares the Label in its `ItemTemplate`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Board}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Do not access any view elements in your view model (that's against MVVM), but simply update collection elements, like

```
viewModel.Board[4] = "X";
```

This would typically be executed by an `ICommand` in your view model, implemented by e.g. a [`RelayCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand).

A simple example of such a command could look like this:

```
public class BoardViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Board { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<string>(
            Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(i => ""));

    public RelayCommand<int> ClickCommand { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(i => Board[i] = "X");
    }
}
```

A straightforward way to use such a command and pass the clicked cell's index to the view model could look like shown below with a Button instead of a Label. Note the assignments of the properties `Command`, `CommandParameter`, `AlternationCount` and `AlternationIndex`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Board}" AlternationCount="9">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}"
                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

As an alternative you may have a view model with a data item class that holds the content of the cell and the command to change the cell content.

A simplified example:

```
public class BoardItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string text = "";

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            text = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand ClickCommand { get; }

    public BoardItem()
    {
        ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Text = "X");
    }
}

public class BoardViewModel
{
    public BoardItem[] Board { get; }
        = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(i => new BoardItem()).ToArray();
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Board}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Text}"
                    Command="{Binding Path=ClickCommand}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks! I still don't get how to implement the RelayCommand, but so far I changed the string array to an ObservableCollection and it now updates the board. I will need to keep reading about the RelayCommand.

Comment: You'll find RelayCommand implementations here on StackOverflow.